# Problem in HashSet - Saving object

Tags: java

I have list of product.That list contain check-box & qty in Text-box.IF the user selected particular product need to save that object in HashSet.

```
 CheckBox    Name  Price   Qty
 []          Pen   21    TextBox
 []          aaa   11    TextBox
 []          bbb   25    TextBox
```

When the user select the checkbox then save that object into HashSet.

```
Set<Product> s = new HashSet<Product>();
Product product = new Product();
product.setName("Pen");
product.setPrice(21.00);
product.setName(10);
//s.add(product);
 if(!s.add(product))
    System.out.println("Duplicate detected : " + product);
}
```

Problem is :

I selected one particular product.After some time I am changing qty for that saved product.
How we can do it:

How to take saved object & change some property & saved back it.

Please help me...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a couple of methods to your `Product` class:

- `public int getQuantity()`
- `void setQuantity(int quantity)`

However, you should not modify an object that is in a `HashSet`: it's safer to remove it and add a new one. In fact, if you modify an object that is in a `HashSet` you will modify its hash value!

Here is some code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().go();
    }

    public void go() {
        Product p1 = new Product();
        p1.setName("P1");
        p1.setPrice(2.5);
        p1.setQuantity(1);

        Product p2 = new Product();
        p2.setName("P2");
        p2.setPrice(5.3);
        p2.setQuantity(1);

        Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>();
        products.add(p1);
        products.add(p2);

        System.out.println(products);

        // now let's assume that you want to change quantity of P1

        Product newp1 = new Product();
        newp1.setName("P1");
        newp1.setPrice(2.5);
        newp1.setQuantity(2);

        if (products.contains(newp1)) {
            products.remove(newp1);
        }
        products.add(newp1);

        System.out.println("after update:");
        System.out.println(products);
    }

}
```

and here is the `Product` class:

```
public class Product {

    String name;
    double price;
    int quantity;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product [name=" + name + ", price=" + price + ", quantity="
                + quantity + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        long temp;
        temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(price);
        result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Product other = (Product) obj;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(price) != Double
                .doubleToLongBits(other.price))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Note that I've overridden `hashCode` and `equals` without considering the field `quantity`. A better option could be having two classes: `Product` with only `name` and `price`, and `ProductOrder` with two fields: a `Product` and a `quantity`.

Comment: I added these setter & getter.e.g Before i set product.setQty(10.00) setInstance.addd(Product); After that I want to take that object & change & save it again... How to do it?

Comment: Don't do it: remove the old object from the set and add the new one. This is safer, because if you change an object in a set you alter its hash code!

Answer (score 1):

Just obtain a reference to the object from your set, modify its value using the methods exposed by the object and the next retrieval will give you the updated object.
can you also post the equals() and hashcode() method of your product class, if you have overriden them?

so something like this :

```
//set.add(savedProduct);
//savedProduct.setQuantity(newQuantity);
//now the product saved in the set has the new quantity.
```

So you don't need to save anything back in, just obtain the reference to the object and modify the object using the reference.

Comment: So if you have an object, that you want to modify; check if it exists in the set and modify it and you will not need to save it back in. Alternatively, if you don't have the object reference, you will need to iterate through the set, apply the search parameter on each element (if iteratedProduct.getProductName()="searchedName" and iteratedProduct.getProductName()=oldQuantity, then iteratedProduct.setQuantity(newQuantity);)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it easier to use a `MAP` for this? You can use the product names as keys and just retrieve the Product object by name from your collection.

```
 Map<String, Product> products = new HashMap<String, Product>();

 public void addProduct(Product product){
   if(products.get(product.getName())!=null){
     products.get(product.getName()).addQuantity(product.getQuantity());
   }else{
      products.put(product.getName(), product);
   }
  }
```

Note that for this solution product names have to be unique. If 2 products have the same name, you cannot use this unless you either enforce unique names or add a field to products that has is unique

Answer (score 0):

As [`HashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) doesn't have any getter method you'd have to get the iterator then iterate over your set until you find the one you're looking for, change it then add.

So get out the iterator then:

```
Product p;
while(itr.hasNext()){
    p = itr.next();
    if(p.equals(name) {
        itr.remove();
        //do stuff to it;
        s.add(p);
        break;
    }
}
```

Do some cleanup in case you haven't found it etc..

Answer (score 0):

While using the Set interface, the straight forward way is to write a search method that iterates through all the elements of the set and searches for the given product Name say 'Pen'. Then you can set the quantity on the searched product. This way you don't have to put the element back to the set.